# Is there a Java Virtual Machine available for Windows 3.11 Workgroup?

Tags: windows, mongodb, javafx, jvm, operating-system

Can you please answer the following questions:

- Is there a JVM available for Windows 3.11 Workgroup OS?
- Can I install mongoDb on such a machine?
- Is running JavaFX application possible for this version?

Comment: Are you serious? Sorry, have to ask. Why on earth would you be using a 22 year old operating system? Oh, and the answer is definitely No for questions 2 and 3, and I'm pretty certain also a No for question 1. Good luck... :-)

Comment: :-)) I' m very serious my friend. IBM cash registers still using this operating system :-( and I want to try different technologies on this system.

Comment: @MahmutAkyol: If some machine is running Win 3.11, I also assume that the hardware specs of this machine would not meet "modern standards". Just out of curiosity: May I ask what processor are you running on / how much RAM / disk space you have?

Comment: If that device is still running Windows 3.11, then chances are very good that the hardware is incapable of running any operating system that has a still-supported JVM. Your best bet would probably be Linux or *BSD, but that would obviously destroy the primary purpose of the device.

Comment: Plenty of purpose-built systems, do their tasks perfectly for decades. One of the top transport corporations still uses DOS in some warehouses. Owners of such systems, reasonably or not, don’t want to change anything. Someday an owner wants some trivial improvement, like sending number of every incoming container to REST service, what do u suggest to him? Spend millions and months for upgrade? Discover peculiarities of HTTP and JSON libraries for some commercial language from the 80th? Or look again at phrases “cross-platform” and “runs even on sim card” in the description of some C++ or Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The system requirements for Java](http://java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml) state the following minimum requirements for windows:

- Windows 10 (8u51 and above)
- Windows 8.x (Desktop)
- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows Vista SP2
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (64-bit)
- Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 (64-bit)
- RAM: 128 MB
- Disk space: 124 MB for JRE; 2 MB for Java Update
- Processor: Minimum Pentium 2 266 MHz processor
- Browsers: Internet Explorer 9 and above, Firefox

So: No.

And please also note that not even Windows XP is supported anymore by Java 7 & Java 8:

> Note: As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and therefore it is no longer an officially supported platform. Users may still continue to use Java 7 updates on Windows XP at their own risk, but support will only be provided against Microsoft Windows releases Windows Vista or later.

Edit 1: I also looked into [Java 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html) but they also only offer downloads for Win 95.

Edit 2: Due to @the8472's comment I did some more investigation and found that http://www.gaby.de/win3x/esoft.htm offers a Java SDK (also suggested in a [superuser Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/92426/was-is-there-a-version-of-the-java-vm-for-windows-3-1)). This *may* also contain a (very very old) JVM / JRE that allows to run Java programs. But keep in mind, that if so, this JVM may only support very old Java versions, an no software that is currently developed based on Java.

Comment: java.com is only about the oracle jvm. there are others which might be able to target DOS

Comment: @the8472: Extended my answer to address this, thanks.